# Why is image not loading in jekyll when hosted in github?

Tags: github, jekyll

I have a blog made using jekyll which is hosted at https://github.com/rocka0/myblog. I wanted to know why my image is not loading in the about me page.

The error for the picture is: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set your `baseurl` to `/myblog` (no trailing slash) and call your image with

```
<img itemprop="image" class="img-rounded" src="{{ site.baseurl }}/assets/img/blog-author.jpg" alt="Tush Chen">
```

Comment: @sharmano ask one question at a time, please (and note that you haven't given a [mcve] of your current search issues).

Comment: @jonrsharpe Sorry. I'll keep that in mind next time!

Answer (score 0):

From [this config](https://github.com/barryclark/jekyll-now/blob/da5c21a55b7352d5555164ddb2f42dcc693e52b7/_config.yml#L42-L50), your [`rocka0/myblog/_config.yml#L3-L4`](https://github.com/rocka0/myblog/blob/8d348b5c2c224d7490073ef9463d643f71f1ac2d/_config.yml#L3-L4) should be:

```
# Your website URL (e.g. http://barryclark.github.io or http://www.barryclark.co)
# Used for Sitemap.xml and your RSS feed
url: http://rocka0.github.io/

# If you're hosting your site at a Project repository on GitHub pages
# (http://yourusername.github.io/repository-name)
# and NOT your User repository (http://yourusername.github.io)
# then add in the baseurl here, like this: "/repository-name"
baseurl: "/myblog"
```

Comment: Could you help me with the search?

Answer (score 0):

The author image (Geekstatic Facebook avatar of Mario) is square in shape. Everything else is OK. The cases are ok. But when I looked at your `config.yml` your baseurl is `/myblog`. Change it back to correct subpath that is `/myblog/`

Also, check if your `url` (# the base hostname & protocol for your site) points to http://rocka0.github.io/myblog in `config.yml`

Comment: im sorry but that didn't work. The page is requesting for the picture from rocka0.github.io not rocka0.github.io/myblog. I dont know why. Is it a problem with the baseurl? I update my repo. Check it out

Comment: Go to `config.yml` and change the baseurl to `/myblog/` not `"/myblog/"`.Remove the quotes!

Comment: thanks it worked. But can you help me with the search?

Comment: there is already a link.title in between but it still doesnt work

Comment: sorry i was poitning you to the navigation. The search is `<a id="search" class="dosearch">
    <svg class="icon-menu icon-search"><use xlink:href="#icon-search"></use></svg>
</a>` . what do you intend to search?

Comment: sorry my bad too. The error for this is that it cant find the search.json file. Again, it is going to rocka0.github.io no rocka0.github.io/myblog

Comment: i fixed it tnx a lot. It was a problem with the link. Tnx a ton for your help!